# watchPosition vs getCurrentPosition in geolocation

Tags: javascript, android, geolocation, gps

I'm interested to find out what is the battery consumption of watchPosition method compared to getCurrentPosition method of the official geolocation API.

Thing is, I could call getCurrentPosition like every 2min, and it would be good enough for me probably. As far as I know/assume, getCurrentPosition uses GPS only once kind of, so the battery consumption of that method is low. But what about watchPosition? I assume that when you call watchPosition, then GPS will basically try to get a new location constantly all the time (that is, until you clear the watch). I know that the watchPosition callback will only be invoked when the position changes. **But the callback is not the thing consuming the battery, GPS trying to locate the device is.** And even if your position doesn't change, GPS is still constantly recalculating (and capturing GPS signals) your position all the time. And this is why watchPosition drains so much battery. **Am I correct with these assumptions?**

If those assumptions are correct, then one could be better of with just getCurrentPosition. As like I said, it uses GPS only once per method call. Though I have heard watchPosition gives better accuracy.